# Volume of solid using Double Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Set up a double integral in rectangular coordinates for calculating the volume of the solid under the graph of the function $f(x,y)=20-x^2-y^2$ and above the plane $z=11$

What i Try :: Let $f(x,y)=z$. Then $20-x^2-y^2=11\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2=9$. Then we have $y\in\bigg[-\sqrt{9-x^2}\;,\sqrt{9-x^2}\bigg]$ and $x\in[-3,3]$

So volume $$V=\int^{3}_{-3}\int^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}\bigg(20-x^2-y^2\bigg)dydx$$

Is my solution is right. If not please tell me How do i solve it. Thanks

Comment: Almost, but your integrand gets you the volume from the paraboloid down to the $z=0$ plane. How could you adjust that?

Comment: I did not understand it.please explain me. What should me the limit of integration. Plesse tell me. Thanks

Comment: @jacky You're finding the entire volume under the graph of $f(x,y)$ all the way down to the x-y plane, i.e. $z=0$. You want volume under $f(x,y)$ but also above $z=11$.

Comment: For $z=0$, we have $20-x^2-y^2=0\Longrightarrow x^2+y^2=20$. So we have $x\in\bigg[-2\sqrt{5},2\sqrt{5}\bigg]$ and $y\in\bigg[-\sqrt{20-x^2},\sqrt{20-x^2}\bigg]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost done:
$$V=\int\limits^{3}_{-3}\int\limits^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int\limits_{11}^{20-x^2-y^2}dzdydx=\int\limits^{3}_{-3}\int\limits^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}(20-x^2-y^2-11)dydx$$

Comment: Thanks zkutch. But we have to solve it using double integration.

Comment: @jacky. Most inner integral is with respect to $z$ and integrand function is $1$. So you can easily obtain double integral - I only show what you have missed in your answer and how to get it: $20-x^2-y^2-11$.